# $I_v=\int_0^{\infty} (c^2 + y^2)^{\frac{v}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} dy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

A closed form (include special function) for
 $$I_v=\int_0^{\infty} (c^2 + y^2)^{\frac{v}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} dy \hspace{.7cm} v>0$$
 required.

I try to solve it by changing  variable, $t=y^2+c^2$,

$$I_v=\int_0^{\infty} (c^2 + y^2)^{\frac{v}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} dy=\int_{c^2}^{\infty} t^{\frac{v}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{t-c^2}{2}} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t-c^2}}dt$$
I think it could not help.

Edit : $t=y^2$ (tnx @Sharkos)

$$I_v=\int_0^{\infty} (c^2 + y^2)^{\frac{v}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} dy=\int_{0}^{\infty} (c^2+t)^{\frac{v}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{t}{2}} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}dt$$

$$=\int_{0}^{\infty} (c^2+t)^{\frac{v}{2}-1} \frac{t^{\frac{1}{2}-1}}{2} e^{-\frac{t}{2}} dt$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty} (c^2+t)^{\frac{v}{2}-1} \frac{t^{\frac{1}{2}-1}}{2^{\frac{1}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})} e^{-\frac{t}{2}} dt$$

$$=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} E\bigg((c^2+T)^{\frac{v}{2}-1}\bigg) $$

$$=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} (c^2)^{\frac{v}{2}-1} E\bigg((1+\frac{T}{c^2})^{\frac{v}{2}-1}\bigg) $$

$T\sim \chi_{1}^{2}$ chi-square with 1 degree of freedom. By [Noncentral_moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Noncentral_moments) I also know

$$E(T^r)=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+r)}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})} 2^{r}$$

Edit: by using $t=y^2/c^2$ (tnx @Sharkos)

$$I_v=\int_0^{\infty} (c^2 + y^2)^{\frac{v}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} dy=\int_{0}^{\infty} (c^2+c^2t)^{\frac{v}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{c^2}{2}t} \frac{c}{2\sqrt{t}}dt$$

$$=\frac{(c^2)^{\frac{v}{2}-1}}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}  t^{\frac{1}{2}-1}(1+t)^{\frac{v}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{c^2}{2}t} dt$$

$$=\frac{(c^2)^{\frac{v}{2}-1}}{2} \Gamma(\frac{1}{2}) U(\frac{1}{2} , \frac{v+1}{2},\frac{c^2}{2})$$

$$=\frac{(c^2)^{\frac{v}{2}-1}\sqrt{\pi}}{2}  U(\frac{1}{2} , \frac{v+1}{2},\frac{c^2}{2})$$

[U(a,b,z)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Integral_representations)

Is there exist a simple form?

I dont know how could get a simple form? or a better form?

Is this calculations valid?

Any help, Any idea, please?

Comment: try splitting the integral at $y=1$, and then use the Binomial theorem.

Comment: In general, this has a closed-form expression only in terms of hypergeometric functions. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Sharkos Any form appreciated.

Comment: @masoud Use $t=y^2/c^2$ then look at the expression for $U$ here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Integral_representations